# Indoor navigation (MapBox perhaps?)

Tags: ios, navigation, maps, mapbox

Good day,

I was wondering, is it possible to create "indoor" maps with Mapbox for iOS (or does anyone have another suggestion)? I have a PDF of an indoor floor plan. I think I need to convert that to the MBTiles ( http://mapbox.com/developers/mbtiles/ ) format. How could I acchieve this?

Allso, when drawning the "walking route" for the person to certain facilities in the building. "it" should know where the person could walk.

Currently I am trying to create something with CATiledLayers (but I am kinda stuck (I can display the map, using "a tile" format.) and was looking and MapBox might be usefull since it has things like 'drawning' vectors on the map, or icons with information and such. For the walking directions I was thinkin about 'dotting' the walking routes so "Dijkstra's" algorithm" could determine the path. How could I go about this in Mabbox, even if possible?

Any help in the right directions would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,

Matthijn Dijkstra

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can likely do this with MapBox. In order to get an image or PDF into MBTiles format, you will want to use [TileMill](http://tilemill.com). You basically need to get your imagery into a geographic format. The easiest way would be to export the PDF as a TIFF, then make it a GeoTIFF and follow [these instructions](http://mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/reprojecting-geotiff/). That will let you geo-enable the imagery, get it into TileMill, then export it as MBTiles. Then, you could use the [MapBox iOS SDK](http://mapbox.com/mobile) to bring it to iOS.

Comment: Yes, this looks promessing. I now have it imported in Tilemill. And I have my 'image' layer displayed on the world. However it covers the entire world. Is it possible to 'drag and rotate' the image somehow to cover the correct building?

Comment: It doesn't sound like your image is georectified properly, i.e., it doesn't have the proper coordinates, or else it would cover the right place already.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a service such as [indoor.io](https://indoor.io) to generate the maps. There are a bunch of indoor services out there and more coming on the market.

Comment: Is this indoor.io down ? What are these bunch of indoor services?